# We continually throw one dice until we get a specific result for first time

Tags: probability, dice

I have a problem with exercise. Basically, I am not sure if I am right and how should it be. That's why if you can solve it so I will understand. I am reading this but I have difficulties and I am trying alone.
The exercise says:

> We throw continually one dice until we have succeeded for the first time a
>   result below than 3.What is the possibility, to be more than 3 tries, 
>   until succeed the given result (the number to be smaller than 3)?

What I did I take this type from possibilities of Geometry:
$f(x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$ but I am not sure until now if this is the type or another. I believe this is it from what I have read

Comment: If I understand you, you are asking for the expended number of tosses you have to make until you get a result less than $3$, yes?  Are you including that last toss or not? That is, if you toss, in succession, $5, 6, 5, 2$ is the answer (in that case) four or three?  Either way, this is an example of a [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: Sentences start with capital letters. There is a space between each sentence. *Sigh*.

Comment: i have been confused little bit with your comments and answers

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? If you have a question about a specific answer, please leave a comment below that answer.

Comment: @TobyMak i did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require the score on each of the first 3 tries to be in {3,4,5,6}.

The probability is therefore $(\frac {4}{6})^3$.

Comment: The question says "What is the possibility, to be more than 3 tries, until succeed the given result(the number to be smaller than 3)" .Example it can be   8 times the dice i throw it i am not saying only the 3 times .I am not looking for the first 3 tries.I am looking for only the first try i got a number less than 3.When i got 1 the number or 2 the number then i will have success.It maybe be 8 trial .I hope you got me now.I think you counted the numbers of the dice 3,4,5,6 .

Comment: No, you only care about the first 3 tries. Whatever happens after those 3 tries don't matter. For example, it would not matter if you roll a die 4 times or 8 times, since both of them have taken over 3 tries.

Comment: thanks a lot man ,so it isnt  Geometric Distribution as i thought?

Comment: Thanks @Kyky, I was trying to think of a way to explain that which wouldn't cause any confusion!

Comment: @S.Dolan man sorry for asking again but what you thought to solve  this ?(i mean type ) etc .It isn't Geometric Distribution what it is i mean

Comment: Are you asking 'How did I think of the solution'?

Comment: I think the best way for you to understand problems like this one is as a sequence of events for which we will multiply probabilities.

Comment: thanks i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You want the probability that you don't succeed  (in getting a number below $3$) in the first three trials. This means you want the first three outcomes to be $3,4,5$ or $6$. The answer is $(\frac 4 6)(\frac 4 6)(\frac 4 6)=(\frac 2 3)^{3}$

Comment: why should i want 3,4,5,6? and not until 10 for example?